# Elementary Row Operations

Tags: matlab, matrix

```
A=  
  3  4  6  1  
 -1  0  6  5  
  8  1  0  4  
 -1 -2  1  3
```

How can I transform A to reduced row echelon form with using elementary row operations. I cannot solve because I can't use the `rref()` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your question is about the use of Matlab, the answer is, of course, elementary.  For example, you can switch rows this way:

```
A([4 2],:) = A([2 4],:)
```

you can multiply a row by a constant this way

```
A(3,:) = 3*A(3,:)
```

and I'll leave you to figure out how to add rows together.

If your question is about the mathematics of reducing `A` to row echelon form, that would be off-topic on SO.

Answer (score 0):

It is useful to be aware of `rrefmovie`, which used to be included in MATLAB but has since been removed.  It takes a matrix walks through the steps to produce a matrix in reduced row echelon form, identifying pivots/eliminations and displaying the partially reduced matrices along the way.  You can download the `.m` file to be used with a newer version of MATLAB [here at the Matlab Central file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23039-matlab-in-physics-matrices/content/Lecture3/rrefmovie.m).